# from 1 d3.select hide another div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, d3.js

I have 2 different divs having different id's `#context-menu` & `#create-context-menu`

```
d3.select('#context-menu')
  .style('display', 'inline-block')
  .on('mouseleave', function() {
       d3.select('#context-menu').style('display', 'none');
       context = null;
   });
```

I want to hide `#context-context-menu` div, not `onMouseLeave` -->
        From this `d3.select` I want to hide another div(`#create-context-menu`).

Comment: d3.select('#another_div').style('display', 'none');

Comment: thanks Kartihikeyan .....
Is It Possible we call another Div from one Other then mouse over ???If yes can u give some sample Code ..

Comment: On mousehover on divA you need to show/hide another div? Is that so.?

Comment: i simply disable the #create-context-menu when control come's in  #context-menu...

Comment: can you please create fiddle of your code ?

Answer (score 0):

```
d3.select('#context-menu')
  .style('display', 'inline-block')
  .on('mouseover', function() {                   
      //To hide the div with id create-context-menu
      d3.select('#create-context-menu').style('display', 'none');
      //OR          
      //d3.select('#create-context-menu').style('opacity', 0);
  });
```

Note: To get the div with id `context-menu` inside the mouseover function, you can use `d3.select(this)`

Comment: Thnks Gilsha...but if i put this code it will work only on mouse over ......i want something that when ever #context-menu called at time #create-context-menu should not come ... i am facing confliction on right click two popUp comes .....

Answer (score 0):

Try this to hide the div,

```
$('#context-menu').on('mouseover',function(){
   $('#create-context-menu').hide();
});
```

If you want to make the inputs to be disabled use

```
$('#create-context-menu :input').attr('disabled', true);
```

Comment: Thnks Kartikeyan ...but my requirement is on click two popup coming having ids of div #context-menu & #create-context-menu   i want to disable  #create-context-menu when we click on node and disable #context-menu when we click anywhere except that node .

after calling d3.select('#context-menu')
i tried 
// $( "#create-context-menu" ).addClass('hidden');
//            $('#test').css({'display':'none'});
Both Works Fine but after that $('#create-context-menu') not comes again

Comment: @Sandeep did you remove the class on close of the popup?